# Can we restart a service in client machine using terminal service?

Tags: c#, terminal-services

We have services installed in client machines. We can not directly access those machine from our local system. To Connect Client machine first we have to connect to the machine from which the client has allowed accessing client machine. That means we have to first connect to one of the internal server using windows credentials and then from that server we will remote client machine using the credentials provided by client. Now is it possible to restart the service in client machine using C# code?

Answer (score 0):

1. Start -> Run -> MMC
2. Press CTRL + M
3. Select services
4. Enter the IP (or name) of the server
5. Enjoy

Comment: Sorry I did not understand this. I want to write a Program to restart the service in client machine.